# How to turn values into variables and assign them a value according to their rank?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, ranking

Given a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,8), 
rank1 = c("apple", "NA", "banana", "kiwi", "peach", "kiwi", "kiwi", "grape"), 
rank2 = c('mango', 'NA', 'date', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'apple', 'pear', 'NA'), 
rank3 = c('kiwi', 'NA', 'apple ', 'peach', 'banana', 'NA', 'mango', 'NA'))

ID  rank1 rank2  rank3  
1  1  apple mango   kiwi  
2  2     NA    NA     NA  
3  3 banana  date apple   
4  4   kiwi grape  peach  
5  5  peach  kiwi banana  
6  6   kiwi apple     NA
```

Is it possible to turn the values into variables and assign them a value according to their rank?

I would like an output like this:

```
  ID apple mango  kiwi banana  date grape peach pear 
1  1 rank1 rank2 rank3     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA  
2  2    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA  
3  3 rank3    NA    NA  rank1 rank2    NA    NA   NA  
4  4    NA    NA rank1     NA    NA rank2 rank3   NA  
5  5    NA    NA rank2  rank3    NA    NA rank1   NA  
6  6 rank2    NA rank1     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA
```

How can I assign weights to the ranked positions using the formula: n-r+1 (n = number of criteria and r = ranked position)?

Comment: I see your input, and I see your desired output, and that all looks good and make sense. But then you say *"How can I assign weights to the ranked positions using the formula: n-r+1 (n = number of criteria and r = ranked position)?"*, and this doesn't make sense. Is that already part of your desired output and I don't see it? Or do you have another desired output that you aren't showing?

Comment: Is the *number of criteria* the number of fruit columns in your second data set?

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad description.  For example in row 3 there were 3 fruits ranked, which is the number of criteria. And here I would assign to 'apple' a weight of  3-3+1=1 and row 6 a weight of 2-2+1=1 to apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `stack` + `reshape`

```
dfout <- reshape(
  subset(
    cbind(stack(df[-1]), id = df$ID),
    values != "NA"
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "values"
)

dfout <- setNames(dfout,gsub("ind\\.","",names(dfout)))
```

which gives

```
   id apple banana  kiwi peach grape mango  date  pear apple
1  1 rank1   <NA> rank3  <NA>  <NA> rank2  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
3  3  <NA>  rank1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> rank2  <NA>  rank3
4  4  <NA>   <NA> rank1 rank3 rank2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
5  5  <NA>  rank3 rank2 rank1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
6  6 rank2   <NA> rank1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
7  7  <NA>   <NA> rank1  <NA>  <NA> rank3  <NA> rank2   <NA>
8  8  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA> rank1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to reshape from the original data frame to a longer format and then reshape to a wide format switching the variables.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#pivot longer
dfl <- pivot_longer(df, starts_with("rank"), names_to="rank", values_to = "fruit")

#clean up data
dfl$fruit <- trimws(dfl$fruit) 
#dfl <- dfl[dfl$fruit != "NA",]  #optional

#reshape wider
pivot_wider(dfl, ID, names_from = "fruit", values_from = "rank", values_fn = first)
# # A tibble: 8 x 10
#    ID apple mango kiwi  `NA`  banana date  grape peach pear 
# <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#     1     1 rank1 rank2 rank3 NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#     2     2 NA    NA    NA    rank1 NA     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#     3     3 rank3 NA    NA    NA    rank1  rank2 NA    NA    NA   
#     4     4 NA    NA    rank1 NA    NA     NA    rank2 rank3 NA   
#     5     5 NA    NA    rank2 NA    rank3  NA    NA    rank1 NA   
#     6     6 rank2 NA    rank1 rank3 NA     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#     7     7 NA    rank3 rank1 NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    rank2
#     8     8 NA    NA    NA    rank2 NA     NA    rank1 NA    NA
```

Since I am using the `first` function within the `pivot_wider` function.  Is is to select the first instance in case there are multiples within the ID as is the case for second row of the original data.

**Note:** 'NA' column will need to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this `dplyr/tidyr` pipe computes the *ranks* but not the *weights* refered to in the question.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('rank'),
    names_to = 'rank',
    values_to = 'fruit'
  ) %>%
  mutate(rank = as.integer(sub('^rank', '', rank)),
         fruit = trimws(fruit)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(fruit), fruit != 'NA') %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = fruit,
    values_from = rank
  )
## A tibble: 7 x 9
#     ID apple mango  kiwi banana  date grape peach  pear
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     2     3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#2     3     3    NA    NA      1     2    NA    NA    NA
#3     4    NA    NA     1     NA    NA     2     3    NA
#4     5    NA    NA     2      3    NA    NA     1    NA
#5     6     2    NA     1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#6     7    NA     3     1     NA    NA    NA    NA     2
#7     8    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     1    NA    NA
```